# Inverse Laplace Transform for the system

Tags: calculus

How one could find the Laplace Transform for the given system

Given G(S)= $((1-e^s )/s)* 1/(s*(s+1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{G}(\text{s})\right]_{(\text{s})}=\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1-e^{-\text{s}}}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{s}(1+\text{s})}\right]_{(\text{s})}=e^{-t}+t-1-\theta(t-1)\left(t+e^{1-t}-2\right)$$

Comment: Would you mind elaborating the answer?

Comment: I don't see any work of yourself so...

Comment: Partial fractions on $\frac{1}{s^2(1+s)}$ and a shift theorem.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got the answer..

Comment: For this answer, how to apply z transforms..